# System date in Posixlt and Posixct

Tags: r, time, posix, lubridate

I am trying to get the last minute of yesterday using `Sys.Date()` in Posix time.

```
force_tz(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()-1), tz = 'America/New_York') + 86399
# [1] "2018-01-12 23:59:59 EST"
```

CORRECT

```
force_tz(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()-1), tz = 'America/New_York') + 86399
# [1] "2018-01-12 15:59:59 EST"
```

INCORRECT

```
Sys.Date()
# [1] "2018-01-13"
```

Why does `as.Posixct` and `as.Posixlt` return two different values using `Sys.Date()` and why is the difference 8 hours even after applying `force_tz` from `lubridate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ever, `debugonce` is your friend. Running `debugonce(force_tz)`, you can see that the difference in output comes from when `force_tz` hits the branches checking first `is.POSIXct(time)` (in which case the default `tzone = ""` is applied); in the `POSIXlt` case, the default branch is hit, where `as.POSIXct` is applied to `time` and `tz(time)` (which comes out as `UTC` for a `POSIXlt` object) is used as the time zone.

---

This comes down to something subtle happening; from `?as.POSIXlt.Date`:

> Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC.

Hence

```
tz(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date()-1))
# [1] "UTC"
```

But

```
tz(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()-1))
# [1] ""
```

What's peculiar is this can't be overridden -- `as.POSIXlt.Date` doesn't accept a `tz` argument:

```
formals(as.POSIXlt.Date)
# $x
# $...
```

---

If you want to use `POSIXct`, how about the following?

```
force_tz(as.POSIXct(sprintf('%s 00:00:00', Sys.Date())), 'America/New_York') - 1L
# [1] "2018-01-12 23:59:59 EST"
```

Comment: @the_darkside I'm finally content with my answer as covering your question; follow up if I missed something